# How to do something in JQuery after animation Finish()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function to move an absolute DIV and I want to execute the setTimeout function. However, JQuery jumps out of the hover() function when it comes to the line $().finish(). How do I execute something after the finish()?

```
$('#header li[class!="logo"]').hover(function () {

    var leftStart = $(this).position().left;
    var width = ($(this).width() / 2) - 22;

    $('#header .pointerarrow').animate({ left: leftStart + width }, 400);

}, function () {
    $('#header .pointerarrow').finish();

    //######This does not excecute###########
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert('succeeded');
        var l = $('#header li[class="current"]').position().left;
        var b = ($('#header li[class="current"]').width() / 2) - 22;
        $('#header .pointerarrow').css({ left: l + b });
    }, 500);

});
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle

Comment: What does *"JQuery jumps out of the hover() function"* mean? Is an error thrown? Which error?

Comment: See the above code, the function after the comment does not excecute on mouseout

Comment: I can see that. You are still not explaining what happens though. [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: It's because .finish() method introduce in jquery version 1.9.1.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
$('#header .pointerarrow').animate(
    { left: linksstart + breedte },
     400, function() {
       // Animation complete.
  });
```

What ever you want to perform after complete animation write inside function block.

Comment: In my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G3Fes/2/ my method workds too, but on my website it doesn't?

Comment: JQuery Version 

After finish it's must have to pop - up alert but it's not popping out with JQuery 1.8.3 but when you use JQuery 1.9.1 it's popping out alert.

Comment: If you have selected multiple elements, each one will trigger the function.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
$('#header .pointerarrow').animate({ left: linksstart + breedte }, 400);
$('#header .pointerarrow').promise().done(function(){
    /* PUT FUNCTION HERE */
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I solved my question in this way (by putting the timeout function before the finish() and clearing the timeout if another hover is performed by the user)

```
var time = null;

$('#header li[class!="logo"]').hover(function () {
    window.clearTimeout(time);
    var linksstart = $(this).position().left;
    var breedte = ($(this).width() / 2) - 22;

    $('#header .pointerarrow').animate({ left: linksstart + breedte }, 300);


}, function () {
    time = setTimeout(function () {
        //alert('gelukt2');
        var l = $('#header li[class="current"]').position().left;
        var b = ($('#header li[class="current"]').width() / 2) - 22;
        $('#header .pointerarrow').animate({ left: l + b }, 300);
    }, 400);
    $('#header .pointerarrow').finish();




});
```

Comment: That doesn't really solve your problem though. If you use an older jQuery version that doesn't have `.finish`, it will still throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you,

```
$('#header li[class!="logo"]').hover(function () {
    var linksstart = $(this).position().left;
    var breedte = ($(this).width() / 2) - 22;
    $('#header .pointerarrow').animate({ left: linksstart + breedte }, 400,function(){
    //animation complete,
     alert('gelukt2');
     var l = $('#header li[class="current"]').position().left;
     var b = ($('#header li[class="current"]').width() / 2) - 22;
     $('#header .pointerarrow').css({ left: l + b });
    });
}, function () {
    $('#header .pointerarrow').finish();
});
```